# Can't access e.target.name

Tags: reactjs

I have an application with different inputs. I want to access e.target.name of Switch, but i get undefined. For getting this i did:

```js
const onChange = (name,e) => {
  console.log(e.target.name)
}

and 

<Switch defaultChecked onChange={e => onChange("test", e)} />
```

link to codesanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-ant-design-demo-o3kro?file=/index.js:1198-1268

How to access Switch with e.target.name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs(https://ant.design/components/switch/), I can see onChange takes the following format:

```
Function(checked: boolean, event: Event)
```

So In your code, you could pass the name attribute to your switch and access its current state(i.e checked) and also its event properties

```
const onChange = (checked, event) => {
  console.log(checked, event.currentTarget.name);
};

<Switch defaultChecked name="test" onChange={onChange} />
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Switch` component returns only `true`or `false`.
If you do:

```
const onChange = (name,e) => {
  console.log(e);
}
```

you can verify this.

If you want to acess the name `"test"` passed as argument, you just acess `name` parameter:

```
const onChange = (name,e) => {
  console.log(name);
  console.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**the switch return a boolean value on change **

```
const onChange = (name,checked) => {
  console.log(checked)
}

and 

<Switch defaultChecked onChange={checked => onChange("test", checked)} />
```